# Centos 6 seems to ignore iptables rules

Tags: centos, iptables

**Solution:**

That hadn't nothing to do with iptables. It was an issue with my router blocking all ports.
I just added a rule to allow incoming connections to VNC ports.

---

**Question:**

I'm getting literally crazy.

I'm on CentOS 6.6 and I just want to add a simple rule to iptables in order to open port 5901 (vnc server) and allow incoming connections.

Here's how I edited iptables file:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT
```

Then I restarted both vncserver and iptables.

Here's the output of `iptables -L`

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:vnc-800x600x16
```

Here is the output of `iptables -v -n -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4428 packets, 5769K bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source    destination 
0    0     ACCEPT tcp  --  *  *   0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 state NEW tcp dpt:5901 –
```

Now:

1. If I try to connect with a vnc client (remotely, not within the LAN, where it works), I got a timeout connection error
2. If I check for open ports with nmap, I got:

   port 5901 filtered

Services are running fine.

I also tried to disable SELINUX, without any lucky.

Comment: If it's working on the LAN but not working remotely, that suggests the problem is *not* with your local iptables firewall but is in fact with a network device such as a firewall in between the outside world and your system.

Comment: @larsks strange fact is that a scan with nmap says me that port 5901 is filtered

Comment: Your policy is on `ACCEPT` already, so everything is open. This is not an iptables issue.

Comment: Yes.   I think you have not fully understood my comment.  I am suggesting that it is being filtered by something other than your CentOS system.

Comment: @larsks yes, it's running on public interface which I guess is 0.0.0.0, isn't it?

Comment: @larsks: I'm not such a SysAdmin expert, I assume that nmap is able to tell me if ports are open (for example both ports 80 and 443 are open and nmap is correctly reporting it to me). So what should I check?

Comment: You should check if there is a network firewall filtering traffic.  If you are not responsible for the local network, check with someone who is.  The output of `iptables -v -n -L` you posted indicates that no packets are ever arriving at your CentOS box.

Comment: @larsks hey, I just solved it by allowing ports on the router configuration page. It worked. Thanks so much.

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, you should add your own answer, and mark it as accepted.  Please don't mess around with the question titles.  That is not how this site works.

Answer (score -1):

Try connecting without iptables running at all. Just to check this is really a iptables problem.

The other thing that comes to mind is that there could be some problem with handling RELATED packets (which seems weird since INPUT policy is ACCEPT).

Also this could happen if your server cannot talk back to the client, so check OUTPUT chain and your routing as well.

Comment: As clarified by @larsks that's not seem to be an iptables problem at all. Going to check if there's some sort of other firewall on local network blocking unknown ports.